# Relation between classpath version number in top level gradle and compile version number in project level gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

What is the relation between class version number written in top level gradle file like -

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'`

and compile dependency version number written in project level gradle file like -

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0'`

I did found all the classpath build version numbers in this [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) but not able to figure out what should be compile dependency version number.

Comment: I don't think you need the former https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I removed the classpath one and my project build successfully. However, google documentation suggests otherwise  -https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating#add_the_google_services_plugin